# How to solve conflict between jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the flowing jquery code for a dialog

```
$(function () {
    $("#WebcamPopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: '80%',
        resizable: false,
        position: "center",

        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        }
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();

    $("#OpenWebcamPopup").click(function () {
        $("#WebcamPopup").dialog("open");
    });

});
```

and the flowing code for html

```
<input id="OpenWebcamPopup" value="webcam" type="button" />

<div id="WebcamPopup" title="webcam">
....
</div>
```

I test this in an empty page and its work, but when I include a jquery file to the page the dialog not work correctly, which mean that there are some conflicts between the jquery file and the above jquery code. I try to edit the jquery file, but the codes in this file is very complex to understand

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: It's more likely there is a JS error in the new script you have included in the page. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Use the Javascript debugger in your browser. Are you loading multiple versions of jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "dialog not work correctly"?

Comment: [**How to use the console**](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: The script that I included in the page doesn't has any error ( I sure of that )

Comment: The error that I have is that the dialog is opened without pressing any button. Once the page is loaded, the dialog appear as if it is not a dialog and appear as a normal div